# DO we need to bundle our js files at the end of production

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am new in JS and was learning how to use webpack to bundle js files. As I found out webpack is best to be used with babel but it turns out that after all js files are bundled and are converted into ES5 thanks to babel, it gets almost impossible to debug the code since the code is difficult to read (because code is uglified automatically). So, the question is Are webpack and babel better to used in the final stage of development after all of the testing was done

Comment: Imho it would make sense to setup 2 different build processes, one for development were you don't run uglify (should be possible to controll that via options)  and one process for production mini- und uglifies the files. This heavily depends on your build process and uglify plugin you use. Wether to uglify or not should not be depending on a timeframe but on the target environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to use webpack always. It useful for js, css, sass, files and etc.
But for debugging your code you need use sourcemap. It compares the map of your written code and collected via webpack.

Comment: thank you Anatolii for your kind reply, you mean it is ok to start using webpack from the beginning of a project and to properly recognize uglified code we need to use sourcemap. Right?